How do I keep a correct API spec when using a ModelSerializer?
I'm using a model serializer to serialize a list as a dictionary (thanks to Plagon). This however leaves me with an incorrect API spec.
How do I ensure the API spec is correct?
from uuid import UUID, uuid4

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, model_serializer


class Item(BaseModel):
    uid: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    number: int = Field(default_factory=lambda: 4)  # https://xkcd.com/221/

class ResponseModel(BaseModel):
    items: list[Item]

    @model_serializer
    def serialize_model(self):
        return {str(item.uid): item.model_dump() for item in self.items}


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/", response_model=ResponseModel)
def read_item():
    return ResponseModel(items=[Item() for _ in range(2)])

{
  "openapi": "3.1.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "FastAPI",
    "version": "0.1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/items/": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Read Item",
        "operationId": "read_item_items__get",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ResponseModel"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Item": {
        "properties": {
          "uid": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uuid",
            "title": "Uid"
          },
          "number": {
            "type": "integer",
            "title": "Number"
          }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Item"
      },
      "ResponseModel": {
        "properties": {
          "items": { // <- this is wrong as it doesn't now about items being a dict now.
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Item"
            },
            "type": "array",  
            "title": "Items"
          }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "items"
        ],
        "title": "ResponseModel"
      }
    }
  }
}


I'm not sure I'm following, so please expand if necessary: If you don't want to document the type and convert the response to ResponseModel, don't add it as the response_model for your endpoint? You're explicitly saying "This endpoint will return something matching ResponseModel, so if you don't want that to be true - either define a response model that matches what you're going to return or drop setting an explicit response model at all.

I want the API spec to match the dictionary that is returned. Any is returned if I remove the response_model from the route. Of course that's better than a wrong api spec, but I'd much rather have a helpful spec.  @MatsLindh

Then write a response model that matches the dict you're returning and set that as response_model instead of a model that doesn't match what you're returning from your API. In this case you could probably define the response model as Dict[int, Item] or something similar (and I'm not sure if you need to call model_dump inside your serializer, as that might be handled automagically for you). You can also set Dict[int, Item] as what the function returns through type hints, and then remove the response_model definition.

That seems almost too easy. It also removes the need for the model serializer. Thanks!
